# How to display custom search results in grid in dynamics crm 2015 online?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm working with Dynamics CRM 2015 Online, I want to provide a way to do a custom search on accounts and display the results in the standard account grid control, basically it would operate like a standard quick search.  The reason for wanting to get the results into the standard grid control is that the results can then natively flow into the various charts for accounts.

What I have so far is a custom button on the account home command ribbon.  I have some custom javascript behind the button that takes in a CRMParameter of SelectedControl, which gives me the grid itself.  I have looked over the grid control object and also dug into the SDK documentation related to the grid control, but I haven't come across a way to put data back into the grid control.  Has anyone done this before?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused, can't you just set up a specific view and apply it to that grid view? What do you mean by "Custom Search?"

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide more detail.  With the command button I want to launch a new window with some custom search controls.  What I want to provide is a radius search on account records.  I have the latitude/longitude data on accounts and the necessary distance calculations.  The only thing I'm missing is being able take results from running a OData query on Account records and put those results into the grid control.  I'm not sure that's even possible but it would definitely be ideal since any charts would then drive off the data in that grid.

Comment: Oh if you have a bunch of records coming from the oData there is no way to put them in the default grid. You need to embed a web resource with a full custom grid. If the plan is to keep those records associated to the main record, you can create an n:n relationship and, with the custom search, create and delete those relationship based on the distance. In that case you will be able to control in how many radius area that record is present in, by counting how many relationships it has

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's what I was afraid of.  Too bad there isn't a way to support that, it would be really nice to customize the searching and still take advantage of the charting for the results.  I think I'll submit a new product feature request for that :)